# Close a CPQ custom action popup that has an embeded LWC

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, cpq

I have a CPQ custom action on the Quote Line Editor, this opens a VF page which embeds an LWC.

My setup is the same as this: https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/use-lightning-web-components-in-visualforce/

On the custom action I set the URL to my VF page, and the target to popup: https://pasteboard.co/73zRzhPpKx21.png

This all works fine, but when the user has finished in the LWC I want them to be able to click a button which closes the popup and refreshes the Quote Line Editor - any ideas on how I can achieve that?